# Out of bounds exception for my quicksort method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, quicksort

When i pass the value to my quick sort method it intialls sets the pivot to the list size but after going through the loop every value gets reset to zero and throws an out of bounds exception.

This is the method in question

```
public ArrayList<Transaction> myQuickSort(ArrayList<Transaction> list){

        ArrayList<Transaction> sorted = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        ArrayList<Transaction> lesser = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        ArrayList<Transaction> greater = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

        Transaction pivot = list.get(list.size()-1);

        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size()-1; i++){
                if(list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0){
                        lesser.add(list.get(i));
                }else{
                        greater.add(list.get(i));
                }
        }

        lesser = myQuickSort(lesser);
        greater = myQuickSort(greater);

        lesser.add(pivot);
        lesser.addAll(greater);
        sorted = lesser;

        return sorted;
}
```

This is the rest of the program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.time.LocalDate;
public  class BankingSystem {

        private int option = 0;
        int key;
        Double newAccBalance;
        String transType;
        Double transAmount;

        ArrayList<Transaction> list = new ArrayList<>();

        HashMap<Integer, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();

        static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InputMismatchException{
                BankingSystem bankingSystem = new BankingSystem();

                bankingSystem.mainLoop();
        }

        public void mainLoop()  {

                option = 0;

                while (option != 6) {
                        display();
                        option = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);
                        if (option == 1) {
                                createAccount();
                        } else if (option == 2) {
                                showAccounts();
                        } else if (option == 3) {
                                transaction();
                        } else if (option == 4) {
                                deleteAccount();
                        } else if (option == 5) {
                                showTransactions();
                        }
                }
        }

        void display(){

                option = 0;

                System.out.print("""
                ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                -----------------------Main Menu-------------------------------|
                ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                Please select option                                           |
                1. Create Account                                              |
                2. Display Accounts                                            |                 
                3. Deposit/Withdraw                                            |
                4. Delete Account                                              |
                5. View Transactions                                           |
                6. Exit Program                                                |
                ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                >""");
        }

        public void createAccount() {



                System.out.print("""
                ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                ------------------------Create Account Menu--------------------|
                ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                1. Create Account                                              |
                2. Return to Main Menu                                         |
                """);

                while (option == 1 && option !=2) {


                        System.out.print("Please enter the new account number >  ");
                        int accNum = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);

                        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the account holder >  ");
                        String accName = getKeyboardString(keyboard);

                        System.out.print("Please enter the address of the account holder>>  ");
                        String accAdd = getKeyboardString(keyboard);

                        System.out.print("Please enter the starting balance: ");
                        Double accOpBalance = getKeyboardDouble(keyboard);

                        LocalDate accOpDate = LocalDate.now();
                        System.out.print("Account open date: " + accOpDate);

                        Account newAccount = new Account(accNum, accName, accAdd, accOpDate, accOpBalance);

                        accounts.put(accNum, newAccount);

                        System.out.print("*Account " + accNum + " added to database* "+ "\n" + ">");
                        option = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);
                }
        }

        public void showAccounts() {
                option = 0;

                while (option == 1 || option != 2){
                        System.out.print("""
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                         -----------------------Show Account Menu-----------------------|
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                         1. View all Accounts                                           |
                         2. Return to Main Menu                                         |
                         >""");
                        option = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);

                        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Account> accountEntry : accounts.entrySet()) {
                                System.out.println("Account key(number) = " + accountEntry.getKey() + accountEntry.getValue());
                                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------|");
                        }
                }
        }

        public void deleteAccount(){

                int key;
                option = 0;

                System.out.print("""
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                 -----------------------Delete Menu-----------------------------|
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                 1. Delete Account                                              |
                 2. Main Menu                                                   |
                 >""");

                while(option != -1) {

                        System.out.print("""
                                 Select Account Number
                                 >""");
                        key = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);

                        accounts.remove(key);

                        option = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);
                }
        }

        public void transaction(){
                option = 0;

                while(option != 3){
                        System.out.println("""
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                         -----------------------Transaction Menu------------------------|
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                         Please select the type of transaction:
                         1. Deposit
                         2. Withdraw
                         3. Main Menu""");
                        option = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);

                        switch(option){
                                case 1 -> {
                                        doDeposit();
                                        break;
                                }
                                case 2 -> {
                                        doWithdrawal();
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        public void doWithdrawal(){

                transType = "Withdrawal";

                System.out.println("Select Account > ");
                key = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);

                System.out.print("How Much would you like to withdraw > ");
                transAmount = getKeyboardDouble(keyboard);

                Double getBalance = accounts.get(key).getAccOpBalance();

                if (transAmount > getBalance) {
                        System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
                }else{
                        newAccBalance = getBalance - transAmount;
                        accounts.get(key).setAccOpBalance(newAccBalance);
                        accounts.get(key).transList.add(new Transaction(transAmount, transType));
                }
        }

        public void doDeposit(){



                System.out.println("Select Account > ");
                key = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);

                transType = "Deposit";
                System.out.print("How Much would you like to deposit? ");
                transAmount = getKeyboardDouble(keyboard);

                Double getBalance = accounts.get(key).getAccOpBalance();

                if (transAmount <= 0) {
                        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value!");
                }else {
                        newAccBalance = getBalance + transAmount;
                        accounts.get(key).setAccOpBalance(newAccBalance);
                        accounts.get(key).transList.add(new Transaction(transAmount, transType));
                }
        }

        public void showTransactions() {
                option = 0;

                key = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);

                list = accounts.get(key).transList;

                myQuickSort(list);

                while(option != 2) {

                        System.out.print("""
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                         -------------------Show Transactions Menu----------------------|
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------|
                         1.View Transactions
                         2.Main Menu
                         >""");

                        for(int i = 0; i < accounts.get(key).transList.size(); i++){
                                System.out.print(accounts.get(key).transList.get(i));
                        }
                        option = getKeyboardInteger(keyboard);
                }
        }

        public String getKeyboardString(Scanner keyboard){
                while (true){
                        try{
                                return keyboard.next();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                                keyboard.next();
                                System.out.print("Something went wrong! Please try again" + "\n> ");
                        }
                }
        }

        public int getKeyboardInteger(Scanner keyboard){
                while(true){

                try{
                        return keyboard.nextInt();
                }catch(Exception e){

                        keyboard.next();
                        System.out.print("Not an option! Please enter a valid option" + "\n> ");

                        }
                }
        }

        public Double getKeyboardDouble(Scanner Double){
                while(true){

                        try{
                                return keyboard.nextDouble();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                                keyboard.next();
                                System.out.print("Not an option! Enter an Integer or Decimal value" + "\n>");
                        }
                        
                }
        }

        public ArrayList<Transaction> myQuickSort(ArrayList<Transaction> list){

                ArrayList<Transaction> sorted = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
                ArrayList<Transaction> lesser = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
                ArrayList<Transaction> greater = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

                Transaction pivot = list.get(list.size()-1);

                for (int i = 0; i <= list.size()-1; i++){
                        if(list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0){
                                lesser.add(list.get(i));
                        }else{
                                greater.add(list.get(i));
                        }
                }

                lesser = myQuickSort(lesser);
                greater = myQuickSort(greater);

                lesser.add(pivot);
                lesser.addAll(greater);
                sorted = lesser;

                return sorted;
        }
}
```

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Account{

    private int accNum;
    private String accName;
    private String accAdd;
    private LocalDate accOpDate;
    private Double accOpBalance;
    public ArrayList<Transaction> transList;

    public Account(int accNum, String accName, String accAdd, LocalDate accOpDate, Double accOpBalance){
        setAccNum(accNum);
        setAccName(accName);
        setAccAdd(accAdd);
        setAccOpDate(accOpDate);
        setAccOpBalance(accOpBalance);

        transList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    }

    public void setAccNum(int accNum){
        this.accNum = accNum;
    }

    public int getAccNum(){
        return accNum;
    }

    public void setAccName(String accName){

        this.accName = accName;
    }

    public void setAccAdd(String accAdd){
        this.accAdd = accAdd;
    }

    public void setAccOpDate(LocalDate accOpDate){
        this.accOpDate = accOpDate;
    }

    public void setAccOpBalance(Double accOpBalance){
        this.accOpBalance = accOpBalance;
    }

    public Double getAccOpBalance(){
        return accOpBalance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Account Number: " + accNum + "\n" + "Name: " +  accName +
                "\n" + "Account Holder Address: " +  accAdd  + "\n" +"Account open date: "
                + accOpDate + "\n" + "Account balance: "  + accOpBalance;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Transaction extends ArrayList implements Comparable<Transaction> {
    private Double transAmount;
    private String transType;

    public  Transaction(Double transAmount, String transType){
            this.transAmount = transAmount;
            this.transType = transType;
    }

    public void setTransAmount(Double transAmount){
        this.transAmount = transAmount;

    }

    public String getTransType(){
        return transType;
    }

    public void setTransType(String transType){
        this.transType = transType;
    }

    public Double getTransAmount(){
        return transAmount;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Transaction compareAcc){
        if(this.transAmount < compareAcc.transAmount)
            return -1;
        else if (compareAcc.transAmount < this.transAmount)
            return 1;
            
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Transaction type:  " +  transType +
                "\n" + "Amount: " +  transAmount + "\n";
    }

}
```

Ive tried running through the code step by step in intellij but cant quite figure it out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd like to make this quick and easy to understand. The problem here is that it recurses infinitely. Everytime it reaches the

```
lesser = myQuickSort(lesser);
```

line is recurses. And keep in mind that the list parameter this method receives shrinks in size every time it recurses. Because, for example, the first time you give it a list of size 100 then it gets sorted into lesser/greater and then lesser invokes the method again and it recurses again but this time the arraylist given as the parameter is less than the first. Until it reaches a point where the list has pivot = 0 in it and when it's done sorting that it recurses for one final time and attempts to run this line of code.

```
Transaction pivot = list.get(list.size()-1);
```

Which attempts to get the Transaction at the -1 index since the list at this point is empty so the size = 0. This causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
This is a very problematic method and also keep in mind that you probably need a base case to stop it from recurring infinitely and also a few improvements in general.
Hope this helps.
Edit: also due to the infinite recursion this method could cause a stackoverflow error

Comment: Very insightful, thank you very much